# Can you define the types for a Typescript file's esm exports?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to have a Typescript's file's exports full signature be defined on a file itself?

Taking the following as an example:

```
// Something.ts
export async function getSomething() {
  const response = await fetch('/something');
  return response.text();
}

export const env = 'production';
```

```
// Types.ts
export type Component = {
  getSomething: () => Promise<string>;
  env: string;
}
```

Is there anyway of importing the `Component` type in `Types.ts` into `Something.ts` in a way that needs to be defined only once? So instead of

```
import { Component } from './Types.ts';
// Something.ts
export async function getSomething() {
  const response = await fetch('/something');
  return response.text();
} as Component.getSomething;

export const env = 'production' as Component.env;
```

be able to have:

```
import { Component } from './Types.ts';

type ThisFileExports = Component;

export async function getSomething() {
  const response = await fetch('/something');
  return response.text();
}

export const env = 'production';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to export `Component` in your `Something.ts`.

This can be done with exports statement;

```
// Something.ts
import { Component } from './Types.ts';
export { Component } from "./Types.ts";
// export * from "./Types.ts"; // Will export everything from Types.ts

export async function getSomething() {
  const response = await fetch('/something');
  return response.text();
}

export const env = 'production';
```

See [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) for more info.

Perhaps what you really want is to use a [Class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), in which case you can simply extend the other class. See [abstract class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes)

```
abstract class Component {
    abstract getSomething(): Promise<string>;
    env: string;
}
```

```
import { Component } from './Types.ts';

export class Something extends Component {
    env = 'production';
    getSomething() {
       return fetch('/something')
         .then((response) => { return response.text() })
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you answering, a class might be the only way out, but what I'm really looking for is for a way of type checking all of a files's esm exports, using a single type definition (instead of typing each of the exports themselves)

Comment: If you are using a decent editor (eg. Visual Studio Code), it shouldn't be too difficult. As far as I understand, classes are usually preferred over random export statements anyway.